Having trouble displaying images on Pepper
In the code below, I've tried to display a photo on Pepper's tablet that was just taken by their camera, but I've been having issues.
import time

from naoqi import ALProxy
from src.common.ip_port import IP, PORT

photoCapture = ALProxy("ALPhotoCapture", IP, PORT)
tablet = ALProxy("ALTabletService", IP, PORT)
tts = ALProxy("ALTextToSpeech", IP, PORT)


def main():
    photoCapture.setResolution(2)
    photoCapture.setPictureFormat("jpg")
    photoCapture.takePictures(1, "/home/nao/lachlan/photo/", "capture")
    print("Image taken")

    # If this doesn't work try these:
    # tablet.showImage("http://198.18.0.1/lachlan/photo/capture.jpg")
    # tablet.showImage("http://{}/lachlan/photo/capture.jpg".format(IP))
    tablet.showImage("/home/nao/lachlan/photo/capture.jpg")
    print("Image displayed")
    print(tablet.robotIp())
    # tts.say("Do you like this photo I took?")

    time.sleep(5)

    tablet.hideImage()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

When the photo is displayed, the idle gif(?) on the tablet disappears and is replaced by a black screen for the 5 seconds before tablet.hideImage() is run. I've tried all of the showImages commented out, and I've also tried preloading the image and also trying with showImageNoCache() (I think I might have done it incorrectly though). I believe it's not an issue with loading the file, because it can play audio files just fine. If anyone has any ideas on how to solve, things to test, or just a problem with my code, that would be great.
Thanks!

Stupid question, are you sure about the Python version? Version 2 is obsolete and shouldn't be used any more. Also, that tag might deter people from even looking at your question.

@UlrichEckhardt pepper sdk only works on python 2.7, please make sure you know what you're talking about before getting shitty with people :)

Getting shitty? I hope it didn't really come across as that. In any case, that's unfortunate that it only works with an obsolete Python but if you're aware of that it's your informed decision.

@UlrichEckhardt yeah it was just how you said it was a stupid question is all. Sorry if I seemed like a bit of an ass. Anyway, Pepper only supports Python 2.7 as far as I'm aware, it's unfortunate but thankfully it hasn't effected me too much yet. Have a good one

Oh, now I get it! That "Stupid question..." was intended as an ironic intro into the question I was asking! I did not want to say that your question was stupid! I am very sorry, that was not good wording from my side!

@UlrichEckhardt oh God I never read it like that! Really sorry about that, now I feel really bad about making you out to be some kind of asshole. Real sorry about that. It's also a bit of my fault as well, I can see how it's read how you intended (I also may have been half asleep when I saw it). If someone was actually trying to say my question was stupid, they probably would've been a bit rougher about it. Glad we resolved all that, and I hope you have a good day.

http://198.18.0.1/ points to the root web server directory on the robot, which is not /home/nao. You thus have probably two options:

either download the image to some remote location with its own remote URL, or
save in on the robot in an application directory and refer to it via http://198.18.0.1/apps/<app name>/.... This directory is located in /home/nao/.local/share/PackageManager/apps/<app name>/html/ and the directory structure is created when installing the application package (i.e. the html subdirectory should appear in the package).

